# How do I detect when a safari webplugin loses focus?

Tags: plugins, safari, webkit

I need to be able to detect the browser loses focus in a webkit plugin I wrote.  I thought I could implement the webViewUnfocus method from the WebUIDelegate protocol but that's not firing.  Does anyone have a pointer to a code snippet for what should be a relatively simple problem?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was to setup an observer that watched for NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification notifications.  This let me cleanup and reinitialize when the app lost and regained focus.